# Mac os app signing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I want to use Mountain Lion's new feature Notification Center. In `NSUserNotification.h` I found lines saying:

```
// Use of these classes requires your application be signed.
```

What does that mean? Should I have an Apple developer account and certificate? I Use the classes like this in Console Application.

```
NSUserNotificationCenter * center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];

    NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];

    notification.title = @"asdasdasdasd";
    notification.informativeText = @"text text";

    [center deliverNotification:notification];
```

But nothing really happens. How do I sign the app?

Comment: NB: The requirement for signing was dropped before release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 2 second google will lead you here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html